# Generate an array of dates based on one parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models, `Worker` and `Schedule`, each worker has one schedule

I'm building a method to generate an array of dates for for every worker.
**How do I specify the parameter so the method generates the dates array for a specific worker?**

Worker model:

```
  def self.labor_days
    work_from = Date.parse('01/01/2014') #Doctor.schedule.date_start
    work_to =   Date.parse('01/01/2016') # Doctor.schedule.date_end
    work_range = work_from..work_to

    work_range.map {|d| d.strftime "%d/%m/%Y" }
  end
```

Worker Controller

```
def show
  @working_days = Doctor.labor_days
end
```

Comment: I dont understand the question ...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you're asking.  If you just want to convert from the `Range` into an `Array`, then you just need to call:

```
work_range.to_a
```